# Google App Engine, migration to HRD

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I had registered a bunch of applications for my google account around a year back. Eg. xys.appspot.com. Some of these applications have nothing deployed in it but when I go to application console now it displays that it is using Master/Slave datastore and I need to migrate to HRD.

Do I have to do a migration of these empty applications even if I have nothing deployed in it or can I now deploy a new application in this and it will be deployed in HRD database?

If this does not happen do I have to initiate this migration process and now, how do I redirect request to xyz.appspot.com to xyz-hrd.appspot.com? I am happy with .appspot extensions google have provided?

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate based on the [Migrating to the High Replication Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration) guide. About the redirection, this depends on the programming language and the framework you are using. In general, a redirect rule in the main handler of your application should be enough.

Also, if the applications are empty, you can just delete them and create new ones that support HRD.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration), the last step makes the old application id(in your case xys), an alias for the new application id(in your case xys-hrd). Quoting from the guide,

> As the last step, you will make your old application ID an
>   "alias" for the new one; thus, if users browse your application at
>   old-name.appspot.com, they will instead see your new application
>   (which you might think of as new-name.appspot.com). You do not need to
>   point your users or update your documentation to a new URL after you
>   migrate.

So things should just work.